# Azure - Application Insights end-to-end transaction not showing all SQL queries?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I configured a asp.net MVC (4.x) webapp with application insights and it seems to be working fine but there is a specific POST request that I know does a lot of SELECT queries plus some INSERT queries.

When I locate that specific request on "end-to-end transaction details" on azure portal, for all samples I analyzed I notice that the SQL shown seem to be missing some SQL, at least those BULK INSERTs I know should be there.

Is this related to the sampling? Is there any quick way to change settings so all SQL queries are always logged? I really want to avoid changing the app (this is a test server with very low traffic).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if [sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) is disabled.

[Configure Application Insights for your ASP.NET website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net)

Example for WindowsServer and adaptive sampling:

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
   <!-- Disabled adaptive sampling:
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
   </Add>
   -->
```

Comment: Thanks! The only way to change this is changing the app? no way to just change a property over on azure Portal?